# Prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying to prepare/bind this statement, but it is failing and not producing an error, so I am struggling on how to proceed.

The `prepare()` call fails with a bool(false) returned.

```
// establish connection
$conn = new mysqli(###, ###, ###, ###);

// here are the record values
$dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$record_vals = array(
    'ticket_id'             => 'val',
    'requester_name'        => 'val',
    'domain'                => 'val',
    'created_at'            => $dt,
    'updated_at'            => $dt
);

// insert or update the record
try
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO tickets 
        (ticket_id,requester_name,domain,created_at,updated_at)
    VALUES
        (:ticket_id,:requester_name,:domain,:created_at,:updated_at)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        requester_name=:requester_name,domain=:domain,updated_at=:updated_at
    ");
    foreach ($record_vals as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(':'.$key, $value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();die();
}
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing PDO and *mysqli*. Don't do that

Comment: For the record, [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is never going to throw a [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)...

Comment: The value of `$value` changes upon every iteration of your `foreach` loop. You may want to use [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: @castis nor does it support named parameters or the `bindParam` method (which is also being used incorrectly here; you can't use it in a loop, use `bindValue` instead)

Comment: You can't use the same placeholder multiple times in a statement: each placeholder must be unique.... ie `:requester_name` can't be used twice:  you need a different placeholder in the UPDATE to the INSERT VALUES, and the value needs to be bound to each of the different placeholders, even though it's the same value for each

Comment: @MarkBaker unless emulation mode is on

Comment: @showdev Look at Phil's first comment. The problem starts there.

Comment: @showdev `new mysqli` with PDO functions; won't work. It needs to be `new PDO...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Agreed. Additionally, `bindParam` won't work unless binding "a parameter to the specified *variable name*".

Comment: @showdev *Aye,* agreed. This looks like some form of *pseudo-code*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two different PHP functions. `mysqli` & `PDO`.

EDIT: This is a way to do it.

PDO

```
    $host = "host";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "db";

    try {
        // Connection setup
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql_query); //Replace $sql_query with SQL statement
        $query->execute();

        while($rows = $query->fetch()) {
           $array = $rows; //Store info in an array
        }

    } catch (PDOException $PDOException) {
        // Get connection errors and exit the script
        print($PDOException->getMessage());
        exit();
    }
```

For more information I would say to go and read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the *"proper"* way to do it. It's *"a"* way to do it but I would at least include the `charset` DSN parameter. Personally, I wouldn't do that with exceptions in a production system either

Comment: @Phil your right, I didn't mean to sound as if it was the only right way. I meant according to the code he posted

Comment: why is `->fetchAll()` in a loop? thats supposed to return all the rows on a single invocation

Comment: @Ghost thanks for pointing that out. I meant for it to be `fetch`. Was probably my IDE